# ANZSCO code for postdoctoral researcher in A.I

Tags: australia

I'm currently applying for a visa, for a work-related visit to Australia, and the application form is asking for the ANZSCO name of my occupation, but I can't seem to find any that correctly describes my job.

I'm a postdoctoral researcher at a scientific research institute in Spain, in the field of artificial intelligence. My research institute belongs to the government, but it's not part of any university. My work is purely academic, but I don't do any teaching.

I could find the following options, which seem at least somewhat related to my job, but none of them sound exactly right.

**1. Professionals --> Design, Engineering, Science and Transport Professionals --> Engineering Professionals --> Other Engineering Professionals --> Engineering Professionals nec (233999)**
This one seems the most accurate, but I'm not sure if artificial intelligence can be classified as a form of 'engineering'. Also, it seems strange that the category 'engineering professionals' does not contain any job called 'computer scientist' or similar, even though I wouldn't think of that as a very exotic job.

**2. Professionals --> Design, Engineering, Science and Transport Professionals --> Natural and Physical Science Professionals --> Other Natural and Physical Science Professionals --> Natural and Physical Science Professionals nec (234999)**
I don't think that artificial intelligence can be classified under 'natural and physical sciences'.

**3. Professionals --> Education Professionals --> Tertiary Education Teachers --> University Lecturers and Tutors --> University Lecturer (242111)**
As explained above, I don't teach and I don't work for a university.

**4. Professionals --> Business, Human Resource and Marketing Professionals --> Information and Organisation Professionals --> Mathematical Science Professionals --> Mathematician (224112)**
Although my work is indeed highly mathematical, it doesn't feel like this correctly describes my job. Also, the fact that it falls under 'Business, Human Resource and Marketing Professionals' gives me the idea that this category is not supposed to describe a job in academia.

**5. Professionals --> ICT Professionals --> Business and Systems Analysts, and Programmers --> Software and Applications Programmers --> Developer Programmer (261312) or Software Engineer (261313)**
As with 'mathematician', my work does involve a lot of programming and software design, but it's only a part of my job, and it seems that this category is not supposed to describe a job in academia.

Comment: Have you asked the research institute you're joining? They may have gone through this before with another person.